# Why does `fmap (take 10) . sequence . fmap return $ [1..] :: m [Int]` only work with some monads?

Tags: haskell

What I wish to have is an endless supply of numbers that are either random or non-deterministic. I went on to program it like this:

```
supply :: Monad m => (Int -> m Int) -> m [Int]
supply action = sequence . fmap action $ [1..]
```

— With `action` being either `\n -> randomRIO (1, n)` or `\n -> [1.. n]`

Unfortunately, I could not take anything from that supply.

When I replaced `action` with `return` and tried out different monads, I discovered that `Identity` and `Reader` work, but they are not so useful in this case.

```
λ flip runReader 13 (fmap (take 10) (supply return))
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
λ runIdentity (fmap (take 10) (supply return))      
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
λ [] : (fmap (take 10) (supply return))
[[]^CInterrupted.
fmap (take 10) (supply return) :: IO [Int]
^CInterrupted.
```

There must be a reason for some monads having this quality of hanging when sequenced, but I do not see it. Is this a strictness issue? What is the hallmark difference, for example, between this Identity and list instance? Why is it that I can have a stream assembled out of `Identity i`, but not of similarly trivial singleton lists `[i]`?

Comment: It is worth noting that this issue with lists of `IO` actions is one of the key motivations for effectful streaming libraries -- see, for instance, [the opening lines of `Pipes.Tutorial`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.10/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be surprising that this doesn't work in `IO`.  You are building up an infinite list of `IO` actions, and then `sequence` turns that into a single `IO` action that produces the entire list by performing *all* of the underlying actions.  It must perform all of the actions immediately because they may have side effects. 
 Clearly, this will never finish.  If you want this to work, you need something like `unsafeInterleaveIO`.

The `[]` example is a bit more subtle.  The following will also hang:

```
> map (take 10) $ transpose [[x] | x <- [1..]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]^CInterrupted.
```

`transpose` must traverse the whole infinite list, looking for anything that might have two elements in it to decide whether there should be a second row.  `sequence` is essentially the same.